# Understanding the solution to "How many zeroes do we write when we write all the integers from 1 to 256 in binary?"

Tags: combinatorics

The solution proceeds as follows:

> First, let’s look at the 8-digit binary numbers $\overline{1a_6a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1a_0}$. In a number with $a_0=0$, each of the 6 digits $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_6$ can be $0$ or $1$. Thus the number of 8-digit binary numbers with $a_0=0$ is $2^6=64$.

I agree. But this counts the situation 10000000.

> Similarly, the number of 8-digit binary numbers with $a_k=0$ is 64 for $k=1,2,\ldots,6$. Therefore the total number of 0’s in all 8-digit binary numbers is $64\times 7$.

This also counts the situation 10000000 for each $k$.

So we are over counting? I understand there might be other ways to solve this problem, but I would like to understand this solution.

Comment: Is “to” inclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking for the number of $0$s that occur, rather than the number of numbers that contain a $0$, so it is okay to consider each digit separately, you are not overcounting. However, you need to consider all the numbers from $1$ to $256$, but you have only included the numbers from $128$ to $255$ using this.

Comment: My brain is refusing to understand this concept: even after you have explained it clearly, i  still don;t get it :(

Comment: Consider the last digit of all of the $8$-digit binary numbers. As you have established, $64$ of the last digit of these numbers are $0$, which means that the total number of $0$s that occur in the last digit of all $8$-digit binary numbers is $64$. You can then do the same process to get the number of $0$s that occur in the other digits to get $64\times7$ in total for $8$-digit numbers.

Comment: It might be easier to consider a simpler case, such as the $4$-digit numbers, which are $1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111$. Using your method, $2^2=4$ of these end in a $0$, and as you can see, there are $4$ $0$s that occupy the last digit of these numbers. You can also see $4\times3=12$ $0$s in the above list of numbers, so you can see that your method does not cause overcounting.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't understand that solution either if I hadn't been able to work it out for myself $-$ the explanation is terribly badly worded! Here is how I would explain it:

Consider the $128$ numbers of the form $\overline{1a_6a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1a_0}$. Write them all out one above the other, and you get a $128\times 8$ block of $0$'s and $1$'s; apart from the left-hand column, which contains only $1$'s, exactly half of the digits in the remaining seven columns are $0$'s, by symmetry. So this block contains $(128\times 7)/2=64\times 7$ zeroes.

Similarly, the $64$ numbers of the form $\overline{1a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1a_0}$ contain $32\times 6$ zeroes. And so on. So we get:
$$64\times 7+32\times 6+16\times 5+8\times 4+4\times 3+2\times 2+1\times 1=769$$
zeroes. But we havent's counted the number $256$ yet, so we must add another eight zeroes for a total of $777$.

Answer (score 0):

Problem best attacked as a probability problem, that runs from $~1~$ through $~256~$ inclusive.

Partition the numbers $~\{1,2,\cdots,256\},~$ into the following $~9~$ subsets:

- For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,8\},~$ 
  define $~S_k = \{ ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+} ~: ~2^{k-1} \leq n < 2^k\}.~$
- The set with only one element, $~\{256\}.$

When each of the elements in  $~S_k~$ are expressed in binary notation, the expressions will range

- from $~100\cdots 0 ~: ~[k-1]~$ zeroes on the right
- through $111\cdots 1 ~: ~[k]~$ 1's.

$~S_1,~$ which equals the set $~\{1\},~$ may be ignored, as having no zeroes written, while the *other* set with only one element, $~\{256\},~$ has $~8~$ zeroes written.  So, it is as if you are starting with a tally of $~8~$ zeroes written.

For $~k \in \{2,3,\cdots,8\},~$ when each element in the set $~S_k~$ is expressed in binary notation, you will have $~2^{k-1}~$ elements, each of which will have $~k~$ digit places, with the leftmost digit forced to equal $~1.~$  At random, with respect to each of the other individual $~k-1~$ digit places, exactly half of the elements in $~S_k~$ will have a zero in this digit position, rather than a $~1.~$

Therefore, the tally with respect to $~S_k~$ will equal

$$2^{k-1} \times \frac{1}{2} \times (k-1).$$

Therefore, the overall computation is

$$8 + \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \times ~\left[ ~\sum_{k=2}^8 (k-1) \times 2^{k-1} ~\right] \right\}.$$

$$= 8 + \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \times ~\left[ 1538 ~\right] \right\} = 777.$$

Answer (score 0):

The question only makes sense if leading zeros are not counted, as it is not specified how many of these there should be. Also the question would be more natural if the numbers were $0,1,\ldots,255$, as these are the ones that can be written with $8$ bits. If we do write each of these with exactly $8$ bits, then there are $256\times8$ bits, half of which are zero (by complementation symmetry), for $1024$ zeros. Now count the leading zero bits: $128$ numbers have a first bit $0$, $64$ of which also have a second bit $0$, and so on, for a total of $128+64+32+\cdots+2+1=255$ leading zero bits. Now take into account the $8$ zero bits for $256$ to get $1024-255+8=777$ non-leading zero bits.

Comment: Though it's a bit odd to simply ignore all eight zero bits in `00000000` as leading zeroes, since usually the number zero is written as `0`, not as the null string.

Comment: @ilkkachu: perhaps, but it gets the right answer, because we were supposed to start at $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I add $0$ to the list for convenience, then account for all of its $8$ zero bits as leading zeros, so its net contribution in my counting is zero, which is correct for the problem since there $0$ is excluded from the list. (But I do take into account the bits for $256$ which I excluded for convenience.) The number of bits that inclusion of $0$ _would have_ contributed (since it is not usually written as the empty string) is irrelevant, since it is not included.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, yes, that's what your answer shows you do, indeed. However, you're also implicitly stating that all the digits of the number zero are unnecessary leading zeroes that can be removed without comment. But that's in contradiction to how the number zero is usually written!

Comment: @ilkkachu This is somewhat pointless nitpicking, but I was not saying leading zeros can be removed, just that they should not be counted. And there is no doubt that whatever digit 0 you write in the representation of the number zero is leading, and also that it should not be counted (because that number is not in the specified range). A fun fact is that in the C/C++ programming languages, it is impossible to write zero as a decimal constant, since the language specification states that any number starting with 0 (not followed by a letter like x) is an _octal_ constant.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, I don't think it's at all clear that the rightmost zero digit in the representation of the number zero counts as a "leading zero". I read your post and had to go back to check what the calculation did exactly because the text didn't make it clear how you dealt with that final zero digit. It never was about getting a wrong result (I don't know how you all got that idea), but on the description of the solution being unclear. While I do appreciate oddities in programming languages, I don't know how C is relevant here.

Comment: @ilkkachu A digit zero is leading if there are no nonzero digits to its left. The relevance of mentioning the C convention is only that they use the presence of a written leading zero digit as a _distinguishing mark_ for octal constants as opposed to decimal constants (rather than use an explicit prefix as the do for other number bases like hex); the idea it that such a digit should mark the intention of the programmer to use base 8. But for the number 0 one has no choice, so every constant 0 is interpreted as octal (which fortunately does not change the represented value), like it or not.